# Setting variable on Click and pass it to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dialog

I am getting a variable of the id of a div like this:

`var value = $(this).attr('id').replace("-", "");`

My html looks like this:

```
<li id="item-1">1</li> 
<li id="item-2">2</li> 
<li id="item-3">3</li>
```

So I get item1, item2 and item3 accordingly.

Now when I press the click and set the value to the ID, a dialog opens. Inside the dialog theres an input and an okay button. When the okay is pressed I want to get that variable again.

So how can I pass the variable OR how can I let know the dialog that I'm talking for that id.

Here is an example:

```
    $("#bxs li").click(function() {
            var value = $(this).attr('id').replace("-", "");

                $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                return false;

        });


    // Okay button from the dialog.


        $(".okaybtn").click(function() {

// value is the variable from the previous function
                localStorage.setItem( value , "test");  
                    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );return false;

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery data:

```
$("#bxs li").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).attr('id').replace("-", "");

    $("#dialog").data("clickedfrom", value ).dialog("open");
    return false;

});


// Okay button from the dialog.

$(".okaybtn").click(function () {
    var $dialog = $("#dialog");
    // value is the variable from the previous function
    localStorage.setItem( $dialog.data( "clickedfrom" ), "test");
    $dialog.dialog("close");
    return false;

});
```

Scoped variable:

```
(function(){
var value;
    $("#bxs li").click(function () {
        value = $(this).attr('id').replace("-", "");

        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;

    });


    // Okay button from the dialog.

    $(".okaybtn").click(function () {
        // value is the variable from the previous function
        localStorage.setItem( value, "test");
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        return false;

    });
})()
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but none of both work. I get undefined on both. Would you mind looking at my fiddle?

Comment: On the first answer, I've missed the variable of dialog. Thanks alot sir

Answer (score 0):

Declare value outside the scope of the click handler so that you can access it from other code blocks.

```
var value;
$("#bxs li").click(function() {
     value = $(this).attr('id').replace("-", "");

     $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
     return false;
});

$(".okaybtn").click(function() {
     // value is the variable from the previous function
     localStorage.setItem( value , "test");
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
     return false;    
 });
```

Comment: It's not my question. If I alert the var value on okaybtn it won't work.

Comment: Alert(value) I get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can store it as global variable - not recommended
2.You can store chosen variable value in hidden input
3.You can sent id value  as argument to dialog function.

Comment: Can you explain more on the third please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but it should work if you declare `value` outside of the two functions as it will give the variable a global scope that is accessible to both functions.

```
    var value;
    $("#bxs li").click(function() {
            value = $(this).attr('id').replace("-", "");

                $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                return false;

        });


    // Okay button from the dialog.


        $(".okaybtn").click(function() {

// value is the variable from the previous function
                localStorage.setItem( value , "test");  
                    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );return false;

            });
```

Comment: Tried it and I get on the okaybtn, if I alert value, I get undefined.

Answer (score -1):

For handling the form input in jQuery UI dialog, you can use the `buttons` option.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
 buttons: {
   "Ok": function() {
          value = $('#dialoginputfield').val();
          $(this).dialog("close");
         }
   }
});
```

Comment: It's not my question... When you click on a link, it gives you it's id. When you change function (such as yours) it has no idea of which variable you're talking about.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to give a complete, working solution. I was just pointing out a way of handling the input of the dialog with a global scope variable. I guess I should have asked you to clarify your question.